# texworks can't find tensor.sty

Tags: packages

```
! LaTeX Error: File 'tensor.sty' not found.
```

however, it is there, in:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tensor/
```

along with an army of other similar files..

I'm using ubuntu..

..looks like I can get around the problem by putting:
    /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tensor/tensor.sty

in the command-line of texworks where it asks for it..  but that isn't a real solution..

Comment: what does your log file show, do other files come from texlive/2013 ?

Comment: @David-Carlisle the log file is long.  what you want to know, I think, is that most other packages seem to be coming from here: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/  ..so I guess I have to add that to the path..  so have to figure out how to add to a path.

Comment: the /usr/share one will be the debian tex managed by your system package manager, the files in /usr/local are an (old) copy of a vanilla texlive installation from TUG (texlive 2015 is current:-) you could put the tex tree from one installation in the path of the other but it's probably less confusing to use the same one so install the package via debian's package manager ro change your PATH so you use the tex binaries under /usr/local/texlive

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It appears that your install is too minimalistic. You are missing the package `texlive-math-extra`, as shown by this command

```
$ dpkg-query -L texlive-math-extra | grep tensor.sty
```

output:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tensor/tensor.sty
```

You need

```
# apt-get install texlive-math-extra
```

While we are at it, consider

```
# apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-extra texlive-math-extra texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-extra
```

Take a look at packages that start with `texlive-` and see what is good. If you run into further problems check what packages it could be in (`dkpg-query` the suspected package with the file) and you don't have installed.

Comment: Leaving everything else as it is, the package `texlive-math-extra` should now be replaced with `texlive-science-doc texlive-science`.